# How do I concat column values in laravel query separated by comma?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to combine column values to a single alias, but don't understand the syntax.

I have done like this,

```
$report = App\User::select('users.name as customer_name', 'users.phone as phone', 
                            DB::raw("CONCAT(`adresses`.`city`,`adresses`.`state`) as address"),
                            'orders.grand_total as total', DB::raw('sum(grand_total) as total'))
                            ->join('orders', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')    
                            ->join('adresses', 'users.user_id', '=', 'adresses.user_id')    
                            ->where('orders.tenant_id',$postData['Tenant']->tenant_id)
                            ->ofRole('customer')
                            ->whereBetween('orders.order_date', [$from_date[0].' 00:00:00', $to_date[0].' 23:59:59'])
                            ->groupBy('users.name')
                            ->get()->toArray();
```

I want to combine city and state to a address alias but currently it gives like 'punemaharastra'.

I want results like pune,maharastra but I am stuck with syntax error. can anyone tell me how do I do this ?

Please correct me.

Comment: `DB::raw("CONCAT(adresses.city, ', ' ,adresses.state) as address")`

Comment: please, upvote my comment if it was useful :)

Comment: @pLe0mAx I dont know how to upvote the comment.